# Copy constructor or = operator?

Tags: c++

```
    class Foo
    {


    };

    Foo f;
    Foo g = f; // (*)
```

My question is, what is being called in the line marked with (*) ?
Is it the default copy ctr or '=' operator?

Comment: Just keep in mind that "default copy ctr" is a misnomer in this case. In C++ the term "defualt constructor" has a special, strictly defined reserved meaning, which has nothing to do with your copy constructor. What is called in this case is "*compiler-provided* copy constructor" or "*implicit* copy constructor" or something like that. But that copy constructor is certainly not is not "*default* constructor".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> My question is, what is being called in the line marked with (*) ? Is it the default copy ctr or '=' operator?

The copy constructor will be called.

Even though the `=` sign is being used, this is a case of *initialization*, where the object on the left side is constructed by supplying the expression on the right side as an argument to its constructor.

In particular, this form of initialization is called *copy-initialization*. Notice, that when the type of the initializer expression is the same as the type of the initialized class object (`Foo`, in this case), copy-initialization is basically equivalent to *direct-initialization*, i.e.:

```
Foo g(f); // or even Foo g{f} in C++11
```

The subtle only difference is that if the copy constructor of `Foo` is marked as `explicit` (hard to imagine why that would be the case though), overload resolution will fail in the case of copy-initialization.

Answer (score 2):

`g` is actually created as a copy of `f`.

A simple way to remember what = actually means, is just answer the question: is `g` already existing?

```
{
   Foo g; //g construction ends here (at ';')
   g = f; // assignment (the g previous value is replaced)
}

{
   Foo g = f; //copy (same as Foo g(f): there is no "previous g" here)
}
```

Comment: At g=f you mean that is an assigment so it is an "=" operator usage, and not a copy ctr right?

Comment: exactly; that's because g already exist, being declared just above.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Foo g = f; // (*)
```

copy constructor gets invoked .Its called copy initialization of object.

If you have not written copy constructor within class Foo then compiler generated copy constructor gets called.